# Double curly-brace syntax in Torch

Tags: syntax, lua, torch

I am trying to better understand this syntax in Lua when using Torch:

```
local ten = torch.Tensor{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}

for i=1,(#ten)[2] do
    print(ten[i][{{2}}])
end
```

Specifically the line

```
    print(ten[i][{{2}}])
```

When I run the code, it prints

```
 2
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1]

 5
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1]

 8
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1]
```

I am familiar with table literals and their basic syntax, but what is the purpose of wrapping the '2' in double curly-braces, and how does it work in the engine?

Comment: After some digging it appears to be a slice operation for a part of the table literal.  ten[{{<start_index>,<end_index>}}] returns a copy of the table.  Still figuring out it it is an actual copy or an in-memory copy.

Comment: I suppose you know that this is a Torch library question, not a Lua syntax question. `{{2}}` does what you probably think it does. The answer is in whatever Tensor returns and related __index metamethod—something I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @binary If you solved your problem please post an answer. Otherwise please say so.

Comment: @warspyking I haven't really solved it yet :)  I'm new to both Lua and Torch.  If I do solve it I will post an answer!

Comment: @binary Well as far as I can tell, each part of the tensor has an __indexmetamethod set so it can handle things like this. Because in Lua {{2}} is just a table containing 2, in a table. I don't Torch's method, personally, because that's a lot of tables being created and then taken out directly after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer was posted on GitHub when I asked the same question:
https://github.com/torch/torch7/issues/501#issuecomment-171290546

---

Have a look at [this part of the documentation](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-).

- When you have single curly-braces, you are creating a [selection of the tensor](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/03c04c6ec77275c16f30ea86d3d7b11bc3233e21/generic/Tensor.c#L935-L947). So ten[{1}] is [equivalent](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/03c04c6ec77275c16f30ea86d3d7b11bc3233e21/generic/Tensor.c#L882-L902) to ten[1], which is in turn equivalent to ten:select(1,1). If you have several indices like ten[{1,2}], this is also equivalent to the slower ten[1][2] (because the latter returns 2 times a tensor, whereas the former only returns it once). If you select on a 1D tensor, your output is a number.
- When you have double curly-braces, it returns a [narrow of the tensor](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/03c04c6ec77275c16f30ea86d3d7b11bc3233e21/generic/Tensor.c#L948-L972), and a narrowed tensor is always a tensor (even if it only has one element). With double curly-braces, you can specify a range in which the tensor will be narrowed, which is not possible with single curly-braces. For example, you can do ten[{{1,2},1}], which will be a 1D tensor of dimension 2, and if your do ten[{{1,2},{2}}] it will return a 2D tensor of size 2x1.

For more information, have a look at [select](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-selectdim-index) and [narrow](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#self-narrowdim-index-size).
One last note, the doc for select is not precisely correct, as it's possible to do a select on a 1D tensor, and the output is a number.